# Summernote js hint return a link instead of text

Tags: javascript, summernote

I need to return a link after type @mention on the textarea of summernotejs, I can do it with code below if pressing 'enter' from the keyboard, but if I **clicked** on the list of usernames the text on the textarea the text disappear and the link doesn't get inserted.

Any advice?

Current summernotejs code using hint

```
$(function() {


        $("textarea.summernote-editor").summernote(
            {

                 height: 100,
                 hint: [                        
                 {
                       mentions: ticketNumbers,
                       match: /\B#TK(\w*)$/,
                       search: function (keyword, callback) {
                         callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
                           return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
                         }));
                       },
                       content: function (item) {
                        var text = item.split("-");
                        var ticketId = text['0'];
                        var ticketSubject = text['1'];
                        var base_url = window.location.origin;


return document.execCommand('insertHtml', null, '<a href="' + base_url + '/tickets/' + ticketId +'">'+ '#TK-' + ticketId + '-' + ticketSubject + '</a> ');

                       }
                 }



                 ]
            }

        );




    });
```

Answer (score 5):

so, going to the issue tracker in github is the way to go.

here's how you do it.

```
hint: {
    mentions: [{name:'John Snow', link:'https://link', guid:'123-guid'}, {object}, {object}],
    match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
    search: function (keyword, callback) {
        callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
            return item.name.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
        }));
    },
    template: function (item) {
        return item.name;
    },
    content: function (item) {
        return $('<a href="' + item.link + '" class="mentionned mentioned-'+item.guid+'">@' + item.name + '</a>')[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working. But unfortunately you continue to write in the link when you use the function. Example to fix it:

```return $('<span><span class="href" data-id="'+item.id+'">@' + item.name + '</span>&nbsp;</span>')[0];
```